# recursive array not working properly

Tags: java, recursion, sorting, recursive-query

okay, so i have written some basic code that is supposed to test various sorting methods (only testing one sorting method at the moment) and find the most efficient. In order for the results to be considered accurate i am planning on running the tests several times on different sized arrays. Rather than manually running the same test over and over again i tried to create a recursive function but what i have so far doesn't work (the base case doesn't quite work and it goes on forever). Could someone please help me so that i can run the test several times using a working recursive method?

Side note, i have writtten about 5 different sorting methods (like selectionSort shown below) and was wondering if anyone has any ideas on what would be the best way to rotate through them in the test method so that i dont have to change selectionSort to something else each time i want to test a different sorting method. Cheers.

```
public void testSorts(){

    int size = 100;
    if(size < 1000000){
        String[] data;
        long start;
        long time;

        UI.println("\n\n======Selection Sort=======\n");

        data = createArray(size);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        selectionSort(data);
        time =  System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        UI.printf("Number of items:  %,d\n", data.length);
        UI.printf("Sorted correcetly: %b\n", testSorted(data));
        UI.printf("Time taken:       %.2f s\n", time/1000.0);

        UI.println("\n=======DONE=========\n");

        size = size*10;
        testSorts();

    }
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say, its java

Comment: what does the recursion have to do with it?.. you do call the method from itself, i see, but that doesn't really make any sense

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this if you passed in the "size" parameter to your testSorts function.  As it stands now, you are just calling the same function within itself with no change, so you will get an infinite loop (in practice a stack overflow).

As a bigger picture comment, I don't see any reason to use recursion for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a method 'test()' containing a for loop which calls your actual test method? Your for loop could increment by 100, like you 'testSorts' method does.

```
for(int size = 0; size < 1000000; size += 100) {
  testSort(size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable `size` is local to the method, so when you increase the size and then call `testSorts` again, a "new size" variable is created inside the scope of the recursive call.

To use this recursively, you'd have to:

```
public void testSorts(int size){

    if(size < 1000000){
        ....
        size = size*10;
        testSorts(size);
    }
}
```

However, I would use a simple loop to increase the size by an order of magnitude each step:

```
for (int size = 100; size < 1000000; size = size * 10){
    String[] data;
    long start;
    long time;

    UI.println("\n\n======Selection Sort=======\n");

    data = createArray(size);
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort(data);
    time =  System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    UI.printf("Number of items:  %,d\n", data.length);
    UI.printf("Sorted correcetly: %b\n", testSorted(data));
    UI.printf("Time taken:       %.2f s\n", time/1000.0);

    UI.println("\n=======DONE=========\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answerers that there is no need to use recursion here, @Rein suggests more or less what I would do.

Regarding trying different types of sort 'automatically', you could:

- Define an interface containing the `public String[] sort(String[] data)` method
- Populate a List in your testing class with the various implementations which implement the sort interface.
- Have another loop either inside or outside the existing loop in your test class iterate the object you delegate search to (depending on whether you want all algorithms at one size or all sizes for one algorithm order)

This would mean that your search algorithms are nicely separated from your 'test harness' class.